# Reference cell location with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I need to reference a cell location with a variable, here is the code:

```
 Dim jj As Integer
 jj = 1
 Do While jj <= x
      if Cells(jj, 2) = "Some Criteria" Then Cells(jj, 3).Formula = "=Cells(jj,1)^2"
      jj = jj + 1
      Else
      jj = jj + 1
      End If
 Loop
```

The problem is that the value in cell C1 (i.e. when cells(jj, 3) when jj =1) literally reads =Cells(jj,1)^2 which results in an error because excel outside of VBA does not recognized cells(jj,3) as a formula or any kind of value.

I need to cycle through the rows moving down. Is there anyway to do accomplish this and insert a formula into a cell that references a cell location with a variable as the row?

Thanks! Anything helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use `R1C1` notation for this:

```
if Cells(jj, 2) = "Some Criteria" Then Cells(jj, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1^2"
```

or you could calculate an `A1` notation formula such as

```
if Cells(jj, 2) = "Some Criteria" Then Cells(jj, 3).Formula = "=$A" & jj & "^2"
```